# SQL INSERT INTO Statement not work VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

seems easy but I don't way it is not work , it gave the error msg ( Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement )   ..

```
Call Connect_to_db

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table2 ( Name, StaffNumber , Title , Number , ext , Nationalty , Section , Sector , Side , Department , Civil , Job_title ) Values ('" & addName.TExt & "', " & Val(addStaffID.TExt) & ", '" & addTitle.TExt & "', " & Val(addNumber.TExt) & " , " & Val(addExt.TExt) & " , '" & addNation.TExt & "', '" & addSection.TExt & "', '" & addSector.TExt & "', '" & addSide.TExt & "', '" & addDept.TExt & "' , " & Val(addCivil.TExt) & ", '" & addJob.TExt & "'  )"
Debug.Print strSQL
cn.Execute strSQL

MsgBox ("Data Added to the Database")

Call Close_db
```

All data types text except ( StaffNumber , ext , Number , Civil  ) are number

I believe that I need Trim before each but I don't think that is the cause of the issue .

Comment: Can you share the generated SQL?  `Debug.Print strSQL`

Comment: INSERT INTO Table2 ( Name, StaffNumber , Title , Number , ext , Nationalty , Section , Sector , Side , Department , Civil , Job_title ) Values ('Ali', 55, 'Mr.', 54654 , 454 , 'KUW', 'Risk', 'COM', 'Market', 1251, 'Supervisor' ) @Sam

Comment: nationalty or nationality?

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message?

Comment: You have a value missing? only 11 in the values list. Is department missing?

Comment: I just add [] for all fields name and it is work I don't know why !!

Comment: @SQB I count 11 values in the statement you posted. `((1)'Ali', (2)55, (3)'Mr.', (4)54654 , (5)454 , (6)'KUW', (7)'Risk', (8)'COM', (9)'Market', (10)1251, (11)'Supervisor' )`

Comment: this the old debug.print before update the code based on your post thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `Job_title` value on the `VALUES` clause. Also you have missplaced `Department` and `Civil` columns.

Here is how it should be:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
  ([NAME],
    StaffNumber,
    Title,
    Number,
    ext,
    Nationalty,
    Section,
    Sector,
    Side,
    Department,
    Civil,
    Job_title)
VALUES
  ('" & addName.TExt & "',
    " & Val(addStaffID.TExt) & ",
    '" & addTitle.TExt & "',
    " & Val(addNumber.TExt) & ",
    " & Val(addExt.TExt) & ",
    '" & addNation.TExt & "',
    '" & addSection.TExt & "',
    '" & addSector.TExt & "',
    '" & addSide.TExt & "',
    '" & addDept.TExt & "',
    " & Val(addCivil.TExt) & ",
     ADD_JOB_TITLE_VALUE_HERE)
```